# MSAL - Exception two- Failed to load instance discovery metadata Android 31

Tags: android, android-studio, azure-ad-msal

One of our android app is using MSAL library (com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.2.+) to validate the user with Microsoft AD. When we run the app in Android 12 - Google pixel device, I am getting an exception.

```
E/AdalMigrationAdapter:loadCloudDiscoveryMetadata: [2021-11-28 12:03:12 - thread_name : pool-45-thread-1, correlation_id : UNSET] Failed to load instance discovery metadata Android 31
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:363)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.convertException(ConscryptEngine.java:1134)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1089)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:858)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:731)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:241)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:220)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:196)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:106)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
at com.google.firebase.perf.network.InstrURLConnectionBase.getInputStream(InstrURLConnectionBase.java:137)
at com.google.firebase.perf.network.InstrHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(InstrHttpsURLConnection.java:79)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.net.UrlConnectionHttpClient.executeHttpSend(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:263)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.net.UrlConnectionHttpClient.access$100(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:73)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.net.UrlConnectionHttpClient$2.call(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:176)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.net.UrlConnectionHttpClient$2.call(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:174)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.net.NoRetryPolicy.attempt(NoRetryPolicy.java:42)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.net.NoRetryPolicy.attempt(NoRetryPolicy.java:36)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.net.UrlConnectionHttpClient.method(UrlConnectionHttpClient.java:174)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.net.AbstractHttpClient.get(AbstractHttpClient.java:47)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.providers.microsoft.azureactivedirectory.AzureActiveDirectory.performCloudDiscovery(AzureActiveDirectory.java:188)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.migration.AdalMigrationAdapter.loadCloudDiscoveryMetadata(AdalMigrationAdapter.java:238)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.migration.AdalMigrationAdapter.adapt(AdalMigrationAdapter.java:119)
at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.migration.TokenMigrationUtility$1.run(TokenMigrationUtility.java:67)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Chain validation failed
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:719)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:570)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:615)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:505)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:425)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:353)
at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:90)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$2.checkServerTrusted(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:163)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:255)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptEngine.java:1638)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:569)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:222)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:140)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:301)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:715)
... 52 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
at sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSPResponse.verify(OCSPResponse.java:619)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.checkOCSP(RevocationChecker.java:709)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:363)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check(RevocationChecker.java:337)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
... 57 more
Suppressed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Could not determine revocation status
at sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.buildToNewKey(RevocationChecker.java:1092)
```

Another error is showing is "Unable to perform cloud discovery"
I am facing this issue only in Android 12.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this one?

Comment: @lcj no, MSAL team is investigating this issue.  https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1568

Comment: Did anyone manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For my case, after I added a line *android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"* in the AndroidManifest.xml, I got this error. I added this line to disable the default restrictions in using HTTP, but after this I cannot call MSAL, so I have to remove this line again.